# Oracle Group By Minute Instead of Per day

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, minute

I have written a query to get the data received per day.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss';
SELECT to_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), status_code, COUNT(workflow_txn_id_log)
FROM workflow_txn_log
WHERE status_code = 'DOWNLOAD_ALL' AND created_date > '2021/08/11'
GROUP BY  to_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), status_code
ORDER BY to_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Now I want to get data with respect to every minute ordered in Ascending Order. I have tried to change date format but nothing is working. How do I do that?

Comment: What is the data type of column `created_date`? `to_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd')` anticipates that it would be a `DATE`, however then you should not compare it with a **string** `created_date > '2021/08/11'`

Comment: Try `GROUP BY  to_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd HH24:MI')` or `GROUP BY TRUNC(created_date, 'MI')`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT trunc(created_date, 'mi') created_minute, 
       status_code, 
       COUNT(workflow_txn_id_log)
  FROM workflow_txn_log
 WHERE status_code = 'DOWNLOAD_ALL' 
   AND created_date > date '2021-08-11'
GROUP BY  trunc(created_date, 'mi'), status_code
ORDER BY  trunc(created_date, 'mi');
```

`trunc(created_date, 'mi')` returns a `date` that is truncated to the minute (i.e. the seconds are set to 0).  That means that the `order by` will be using date comparison semantics to sort the dates rather than string comparison semantics which is what you want.  The `where` clause is comparing `created_date` against a `date` rather than a string so that you're not doing implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the date as a formatted string then use `TO_CHAR` and include the hours and minutes:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi'),
       status_code,
       COUNT(workflow_txn_id_log)
FROM   workflow_txn_log
WHERE  status_code  = 'DOWNLOAD_ALL'
AND    created_date > DATE '2021/08/11'
GROUP BY
       TO_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi'),
       status_code
ORDER BY
       TO_CHAR(created_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi');
```

If you want the date as a `DATE` data type then `TRUNC`ate the value to the minutes (and zero the seconds):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(created_date, 'MI'),
       status_code,
       COUNT(workflow_txn_id_log)
FROM   workflow_txn_log
WHERE  status_code  = 'DOWNLOAD_ALL'
AND    created_date > DATE '2021/08/11'
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(created_date, 'MI'),
       status_code
ORDER BY
       TRUNC(created_date, 'MI');
```

*Note: a `DATE` is a binary data type and is stored with no format. Certain client applications (i.e. SQL Developer or SQL/Plus) may chose to use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to **display** the date with a format but that is functionality of the client application and not of the database and cannot be relied upon to provide consistent behaviour across different clients (i.e. the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter will have no effect displaying dates in Java, C#, PHP, Python, etc.).*